# Everything is Yajna

Tags: vishnu-purana, yajna

What verse of Vishnu purana compares every incident and activity happening in this universe as a yajna-karma? and how does the bad incidents like appereance of kali and birth of kali(people getting wicked) be described as yajna?

How do vishitadvaita philosopher's explain this notion of everything is yajna? Is this core concept of vedanta and pancharatra??

Comment: @Tezz yeah its related but not the exact answer that I want